# 4-digit Password Setup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What is the best (and quickest) way to setup a simple 4-diget password in my app?

It needs to be editable by the user. And it needs to be savable on the device itself.

Is a NSUserDefaults a safe place to store the password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to add anything to do with password into the user KeyChain on the device- 
[Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html)

iOS will take of decrypting and encrypting the information for you.  And when the user sync and or replace his device, the Keychain will be on his new device.

Comment: Is a NSUserDefaults a safe place to store the password?

Answer (score 4):

A password of any kind is considered a sensitive information and you (as a developer) should handle it properly.

The proper way to store password is to use the [Keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html).

I wouldn't store any kind of password in the `NSUserDefaults`

Is there a reason you insisted on using `NSUserDefaults` instead of the keychain?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the spinning wheel control with 4 spinners, each having digits 0-9

Comment: I need the actual best way to save off the password securely.

Comment: You may wanna put that in your actual question cause it wasn't clear to me at least! Also, you want to store the password on the device itself or remotely?